# ios uilabel tail truncated trailing dot color

Tags: ios, uilabel

not sure if this has been asked before.

I got a UILabel that is white text on purple background colour.

What I notice is the tail truncation `...` are not white colour but a grey color.

Is there a way to change the color to be white, matching the UILabel text color ?

Comment: It only appeared in iOS 8.1, as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];

NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color }];

self.label.attributedText = text;
```

Comment: =/ That's just bull :P Seems like a bug in the iOS system to me.